# When click on dropdown item it should show over dashboard and remove from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of grids that are not shown over dashboard right now and I need to show these grids over dashboard so I click on dropdown item so it should show over the dashboard and remove from the dropdown list. I am using .hide() of jquery to hide that item from dropdown list. In first case it would remove the items from the dropdown list.

And I have cross button over the grid if user can click over the cross button the item should be visible in drop-down list. but if I repeat the steps the the item not hide from the drop-down list.

```
var name = "#" + e.getAttribute("name");
            $(name).hide();
            var widgetId = "#" + e.getAttribute("name") + "Widget";
            $(widgetId).addClass("widget");
            //$("#" + e.getAttribute("gridName") + "Grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
            $(widgetId).show();
            CreateWidgets();
```

I am using this code to remove item from the grid and redraw the grid.

Thanks
Prince Chopra

Comment: Would you please update whether the answer works for you or not. if it works, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to get an idea about how to fix this,

http://jsfiddle.net/FhcFy/

Sample Html

```
<select id="gridSelection">
    <option value="0">Select a option</option>
    <option value="1">grid 1</option>
    <option value="2">grid 2</option>
    <option value="3">grid 3</option>
    <option value="4">grid 4</option>
    <option value="5">grid 5</option>
</select>
<button id="show">show</button>
<div class="gridContainer">
    <div id="grid1">Grid 1<span>x</span>    
    </div>
    <div id="grid2">Grid 2<span>x</span>    
    </div>
    <div id="grid3">Grid 3<span>x</span>    
    </div>
    <div id="grid4">Grid 4<span>x</span>    
    </div>
    <div id="grid5">Grid 5<span>x</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript,

```
$(document).on("click", "#show", function (e) {
    var selectedGrid = $("#gridSelection").val();
    $("#gridSelection option[value=" + selectedGrid + "]").hide();
    $("#gridSelection").val(0);
    $(".gridContainer").find("#grid" + selectedGrid).data("option", selectedGrid).show();    
});

$(".gridContainer").on("click", "span", function () {
    var grid = $(this).closest("div");
    grid.hide();
    $("#gridSelection option[value=" + grid.data("option") + "]").show();
});
```